# can't find or open anaconda navigator on windows

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, sublime-anaconda

i'm trying to search for anaconda that i've installed , i can't find it in the start menu ,i've tried to search it in anaconda files it shows me a json file and i can't open the app at all , also my cmd can't recognize the python\py con\  at all , the only thing it shows in menu is "anaconda prompt" , 
I've attached an image
**i've tried to install and re-install couple of times but didn't work also!
[image]

Comment: can you share which version of conda you use, run `conda info` in windows command